# jquery grid panel/datatable/spreadsheet

Tags: jquery, gridview

I'm starting a project that requires basic CRUD operations, paging, sorting... on a set of data through a web page and I'd like to do the view part in jQuery.
I've googled free grid panel and jquery and I found lots of libraries: datatables, YUI datatable, extJs....
Any recommendation?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Here someone tell about one very good grid plugin (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766974/jquery-grid-plugin-with-olap-suport).

Answer (score 1):

I've found [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/examples/) to be very good (at least for paging and sorting). The API and examples are fairly extensive and you can customize the asynchronous requests quite well to adapt them to your needs (depending on how the service providing the data is implemented).

I'm not sure how ExtJS interacts with jQuery. The default look and feel is definitely different to most default jQuery widgets/libraries, although that could probably be changed. (Another thing to look at is its licence, GPL or commercial, which isn't the same as jQuery, if that's an issue.)